# Latex Back Referencing Overfull \hbox Problem with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, warnings, back-referencing

I encountered an issue with hyperref, as I wrote a long thesis.
I have to \cite{} some references very often, then the back referencing becomes longer than one line (see the picture below). When this happens, I encounter the "Overfull \hbox" warning, which I really do not like (I want the output message without any warning and error).
People seldom cite one reference in many pages, however, this is what I have to do. Since the back referencing number (links) becomes long, and do not break into multiple lines, this "Overfull \hbox" warning seems will not disappear, as I am continuing expanding my document pages (and citations to the same reference).
Are there any way to suppress this warning, or a command to make long back referencing into multiple lines? Thank you very much!

[image]
This is one example with long backref, which encoutered the "Overfull \hbox" warning.
The below is how I use the [hyperref] package.

\usepackage[bookmarks=true, %only needed for PDF generation
colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta,urlcolor=cyan, %link/ref/url colors
linktoc=page,backref=page]{hyperref}
%%backref=page in hyperref: back references in bibliography to show pages# of cited reference
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

The warning is at \openout9 = `TestBackref.brf'.
Overfull \hbox (15.64209pt too wide) in paragraph at lines

I finally put a link for minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB) at this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZeTHZnV8AuW-x23jPEhFE8KLXdz-YMp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You need to provide more details of your general set-up.  This is best done as a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).  Note that the latest hyperref documentation provides examples of ways of customising the back references.  Perhaps those help.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for comment. I put a link for the  minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB) here: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZeTHZnV8AuW-x23jPEhFE8KLXdz-YMp/view?usp=sharing 

When the backref lists become longer than one line, you want to suppress the warning "overfall \hbox", or you want to break into multiple lines. I think this is kind of bug with hyperref, as testing cases may have not considered such special situation. I would greatly appreciate if anyone can solve this issue, or if the hyperref team could improve this package itself. Thanks!

Comment: This shows a more severe problem with hyperref, which I believe is a bug in the hyperref package.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598588/latex-hyperref-package-cannot-break-line-when-the-backref-is-too-long-overfull

Comment: it is not a bug in hyperref, it is wrong user input. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598588/2388

Comment: The link that Ulirke Fischer provides, give an answer that fixes the problem, so I believe this should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Ulrike, Thank you so much for the troubleshooting. It solved a long-time headache. I never suspected the \textsuperscript . Your solution works as a charm!